# vuejs dynamically bind text in class attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to dynamically change the text of an `fa icon` depending on what an object in the data (iterating in for loop) contains:

```
<ul id="example-1">
            <li v-for="item in cards" :key="item.id">
                <i class="fa fa-cc-{{item.brand}} fa-2x" style="color:black"></i> {{ item.brand }}
            </li>
</ul>
```

This doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You can make class as dynamic attribute as below

```
:class="`fa fa-cc-${item.brand}`"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that would be the correct way of doing it (string concatenation):

```
<ul id="example-1">
    <li v-for="item in cards" :key="item.id">
         <i :class="'fa fa-cc-'+item.brand+' fa-2x'" style="color:black"></i> {{ item.brand }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

or different syntax with ECMAScript 6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
<ul id="example-1">
    <li v-for="item in cards" :key="item.id">
         <i :class="`fa fa-cc-${item.brand} fa-2x`" style="color:black"></i> {{ item.brand }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

You can see that I used [dynamic class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).